# TypeScript class to another class

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, class

I have class values and I want to store it another class.

```
function values(data1,data2){
   this.one = data1;
   this.sec = data2;
}
```

I want store in another class this class values like ->

```
let ad = AnotherClass();
ad.fill(values(1,2));
ad.fill(values(5,2));
```

And I don't know how to build this AnotherClass() to store this values, thanks for the help!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Just add an array property to `AnotherClass` as well as a `fill` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell `values` what `this` refers to.  I'm not sure what `.fill` does, but you could probably just use [.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), and do it like this:

```js
var ad = {}

function values(data1,data2){
    this.one = data1;
    this.sec = data2;
}

 values.call(ad, 1, 2);
 values.call(ad, 5, 2)

 console.log(ad); // {one: 5, sec: 2}
```